# how to get multiple input in C language?

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm new in C and would love to get some help regarding multipule input 
for example I have this struct:

```
typedef struct person{
    char * name;
    int age;
  }
```

and I want to write a function that get's :name age name age name age... 
Is there a way I can do that ? how can I later get the values?

I mean something like :

```
void my_func(char* name, int age , char* name1,int age1.....)
```

like in JAVA I can use "..." 
I want to do something like that :

```
void my_func(char* name, int age , char* name1,int age1.....){ 
  int num_of_ppl = length of the input/2
  person p1 ;
  p1.name = first input name
  p1.age = first input age
```

etc..

thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some of the things you tried to give us a starting point ?

Comment: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html

Comment: What is the relation between *multiple inputs* (presumably from some input stream) and *variadic functions*? Your terminology is wrong and confused me: inputs are not arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a function with variable argument list you can use **va_list**

```
#include <cstdarg>
using namespace std;
void myFunction(int num, ...)
{
    va_list arguments;                           // A place to store the list of arguments
    va_start ( arguments, num );                 // Initializing arguments to store all values after num
    for ( int x = 0; x < num; x++ )              // Loop until all numbers are added
        func(va_arg ( arguments, person ));      // get next value of argument and call a function
    va_end ( arguments );                        // Cleans up the list

}
```

Comment: Please, don't use "u", use "you" instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the vararg functionality in `stdarg.h`:

```
//
// First argument specifies the number of name/age pairs supplied
//
void my_func(int persons, char *name1, int age1, ...) {
  int age, i;
  char *name;
  va_list vl;
  va_start(vl, age1);

  for (i = 1; i < persons; i++) {
    name = va_arg(vl, char*);
    age = va_arg(vl, int);
    // Do something with the values
  }

  va_end(vl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *C* language is a very low-level language, so you'll need to decide how to handle each field.

In your case you need to decide what is the `name`, who owns the pointed data,  and code appropriately, perhaps something like:

```
typedef struct person_st {
    char* name; // malloc-ed string
    int age; 
} Person;

// allocate a Person of given name and age
Person* make_person(const char* n, int a) {
   if (!n || a<0) return NULL;
   Person* p = malloc(sizeof(Person));
   if (!p) 
     perror("malloc Person"), exit(1);
   p->name = strdup(n);
   if (!p->name) 
     perror("strdup Person"), exit(1);
   p->age = a;
   return p;
} 

// destroy a Person and the data inside
void destroy_person(Person*p) {
   if (!p) return;
   free (p->name);
   free (p);
}

// read and allocate a Person
Person* input_person(FILE*f) {
   if (!f) return NULL;
   char name[104];
   int age;
   memset (name, 0, sizeof(name));
   age = 0;
   if (fscanf(f, " %100[A-Za-z] %d", &name, &age)<2) 
     return NULL;
   return make_person(name, age);
}
```

with the convention that the caller of `input_person` should call `destroy_person` appropriately.

I might have misunderstood your question. Do you want to code simply a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) (which has no relation to input or output)? Then use carefully [`<stdarg.h>` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h). Be aware that variadic functions are poorly typed in C. With GCC, you can give the [sentinel function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), and you could even customize GCC e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org) to add some type checking.

Comment: thank you! I looked at the "variadic function" and it seems to be the thing I'm looking!!! thank you!:)